# Creating a long-running Workflow Service

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432975.aspx) in order to learn more about workflow services and how they work.  Now I'm possibly crazy but I'm having problems with the client section of the tutorial (I'm tempted to blame the tutorial and not myself for this issue).  I'm getting refrence errors on the StartOrderClient initialization and the AddItemClient.  Is this just a case of a slightly incomplete step in the tutorial or am I missing something?

I thank you greatly in advance.

Below is my Order Client Console Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activities;

namespace OrderClient.OrderService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Send initial message to start the workflow service
            Console.WriteLine("Sending start message");
            StartOrderClient startProxy = new StartOrderClient();
            string orderId = startProxy.StartOrder("Kim Abercrombie");

            // The workflow service is now waiting for the second message to be sent
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow service is idle...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to send an add item message to reactivate the workflow service...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Send the second message
            Console.WriteLine("Sending add item message");
            AddItemClient addProxy = new AddItemClient();
            AddItem item = new AddItem();
            item.p_itemId = "Zune HD";
            item.p_orderId = orderId;

            string orderResult = addProxy.AddItem(item);
            Console.WriteLine("Service returned: " + orderResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors. StartOrderClient and AddItemClient which I don't believe get defined in the tutorial.

The type or namespace name 'StartOrderClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'AddItemClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What sort of reference errors? That is, specifically, what are your errors?

Comment: Type or namespace name not found.  I'll throw the code of the client up in the main question which might help.

Comment: Where/when does the error occur?

Comment: When attempting to build the solution (sorry, I should have been more specific earlier)

Comment: OK...you still need to be more specific. The error window should tell you **what type or namespace** isn't found. I'll need that information to help you.

Comment: Going to add it to the initial question,  putting it at the bottom.

Comment: Asking the obvious, but did you add a service reference to the workflow service and specify `OrderService` as the namespace?

Comment: @IvanS If you've added the service reference to your client project, you'll need to add a "using" statement, something like `using OrderService`

Comment: Did add the service reference and specified it to be OrderService.  I added the namespace OrderClient.Orderservice to reference which links up the AddItem function.  Typing using OrderService throws an error, it makes me bind to OrderClienr.OrderService.   Irregardless the StartOrderClient and AddItemClient don't seem to link.  I'm suspecting the tutorial doesn't include those after looking through it a few times to make sure so I'm confused where those come into play and link up.

Comment: If you right click on either `StartOrderClient` or `AddItemClient`, does Visual Studio give you an option to RESOLVE the reference (it'd be at the top of the context menu).

Comment: No it does not give me the option to resolve the refrence

Comment: I do get the options to generate a class for them or generate new type.

Comment: Is it just simply the tutorial/example being bad?

Comment: I don't want to build the example to test this, but if I'm reading the tutorial correctly they mean for you to name the client's namespace "OrderService". `namespace OrderService` rather than `namespace OrderClient.OrderService`

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 always gives me trouble with namespaces.  When I have it as OrderService, the section of code that contains AddItem (which is an operation defined by the tutorial in OrderService, also throws an error).  The error is again the type or namespace name AddItem could not be found.  So I think in my situation the namespace isn't the problem.  Though I could be wrong obviously.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, open up the Service1.xamlx file. Click on `ReceiveStartOrder` and change the `ServiceContractName` property to `{http://tempuri.org/}IStartOrder` (it is usually `{http://tempuri.org/}IService}` by default). Do the same thing for the `ReceiveAddItem` activity (`IAddItem`).

Rebuild the solution. In the console project, right-click the `OrderService` service reference and update it.

Note: the tutorial is filled with errors, and I'm still working through it. Once I successfully complete  it and document the missing steps and inaccuracies, I will update this answer and may include a blog post link with a revised tutorial.

For anyone attempting to do this tutorial, a better option is to follow [this updated tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-deed2cd5).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Send initial message to start the workflow service
        Console.WriteLine("Sending start message");

        ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
        string orderId = proxy.StartOrder("Kim Abercrombie");

        // The workflow service is now waiting for the second message to be sent
        Console.WriteLine("Workflow service is idle...");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to send an add item message to reactivate the workflow service...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Send the second message
        Console.WriteLine("Sending add item message");
        AddItem item = new AddItem();
        item.p_itemId = "Zune H";
        item.p_orderId = orderId;

        string orderResult = proxy.AddItem(item);
        Console.WriteLine("Service returned: " + orderResult);
    }
```